# Is there a latin phrase, used in English, to mean after something was created?

Tags: phrase-requests, latin

Is there a Latin phrase, used in English, to mean after something was created?

Of course, there's the phrase

> creatio ex nihilo

Meaning something was created from nothing. But what about 'after creation'? So I could use it in place of the following in bold

> **After it was created**, God was happy with the world.

Comment: So like *post creationem*? That feels like a Latin question - how would you define use in English? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for *[post factum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post-factum)*, meaning "After the fact". Thus, one would get a sentence like:

> Post factum, God was happy with the world.

Comment: nb factum means something done or made. great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is [**a posteriori**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20posteriori):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : inductive
>   **2** : relating to or derived by reasoning from observed facts
>   — compare A PRIORI

The most relevant sense of the opposite [*a priori*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20priori) here is the following:

> **2 b** : formed or conceived beforehand

If something is *a priori*, it is based on something *before* it occurs or is known. In contrast, if something is *a posteriori*, it is based on something *after* it occurs or is known.

---

In the example sentence:

> God was happy with the world *a posteriori*.

Or, in other words:

> God was happy with the world *[after the fact / after it was created]*.

Comment: I would buy this if you altered the sentence a tiny bit: *God was happy with his creation [of the world] a posteriori.*

Comment: “And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good.” Genesis 1:31.  Post hoc.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I'm not a believer, and I know very little about religion, so this might not be right, but I had the impression God is thought by some to be responsible for a whole slew of things, not just creation.

Comment: @JasonBassford - So, *a priori*, if we talk about God having done something *a posteriori*, we won't know  in relation to what!

Comment: @JasonBassford - For me, it's not a philosophical discussion.  My focus is clear communication about ideas, between human beings.  I did upvote your answer.  I only suggested a small addition to avoid the reader misunderstanding the writer's intent.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I just keep trying to say the same thing -- that without context, "God was happy with the world a posteriori" isn't as clear as it could be, and therefore I propose a small addition: "God was happy with his creation [of the world] a posteriori."  But you don't have to make the addition if you don't want to, though -- it's your answer.

Comment: @JasonBassford - What would?  In my last comment, there was no appearance of "a priori."

Comment: @aparente001 The use of either *a priori* or *a posteriori* doesn't normally mention an event that came before or after. You would say *I had **a priori** knowledge* or *I came to realize it* ***a posterieori***. The thing that is mentioned doesn't directly refer to something it's in relation to. That's all given *in context*. Saying *happy with his creation of the world* puts focus on the *creation*, not on the word itself. What's *a posteriori* is happiness with the world. The creation of the world is the type of event that is *not* normally used with either of those Latin phrases.

Comment: @aparente001 In fact, if you used the wording you suggest, it would imply that his happiness was not with the world, but with his *creation* of the word. And that what the creation itself was *a posteriori* to was something else—perhaps the planning of its creation. But the point is that the thing something is relative to is not directly mentioned in any phrase using the Latin term.